# Unable to edit, remove or add CMS pages

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, cms

I have a very strange problem with my magento production environment. When I want to edit, add or remove a CMS page. The system gives me the following error:

> A Page with the same URL already exists

Even when I want to edit a page to add new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! It was pretty simple afterwards. If you want to export your CMS pages there is a plugin from firegento. When you install this it will lock your CMS pages.

Comment: have you raised this issue with the firegento repo on github? also feel free to accept your answer if the problem is now fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions, it sometime happened when you have multiple store & you deleted. 
Execute below query in MySQL.

```
DELETE FROM cms_page_store WHERE store_id NOT IN (SELECT store_id FROM core_store)
```

If this solution didn't worked, Just provide me your log & report details. I'll look further.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatly this didn't do the trick. Where to find the log & report details?

Comment: enable your magento log & then you can find log in var/log folder, Also reports file under var/report

Comment: I have various log files. Which one do you want?

Comment: Latest one, Check modified time & date.

Comment: I've seen a lot of notices about Notice: Undefined index: Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite

Comment: This is not enough data to trace the bug, you can send me the login detail or add me on skype so i can assist you there.
Skype: amalik62

Comment: I've added you on skype